# Any tool for inspecting GTK3 elements?

Tags: gui, gtk3

[`gtkparasite`](http://chipx86.github.com/gtkparasite) is great for `gtk+2`, but unfortunately it won't work with `gtk+3`.

Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking at all the possibilities that can resolve the problem, I suggest the following link which is about how to port `gtkparasite` to GTK3. Although it is a bit technical, the effort is successful.

http://code.google.com/p/gtkparasite/issues/detail?id=18

Comment: I just did that and thought to report, but there you are :) Patch from comment 5 works great!

Comment: [GTK3 is apparently now supported](https://github.com/chipx86/gtkparasite/pull/2#issuecomment-26670246) (since Oct 2013...), you need to compile it from source using the `./autogen.sh --with-gtk=3.0`, `make` and `sudo make install`. The packaged fedora version still only supports GTK2 though :(

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there's now an official GNOME tool called [`GtkInspector`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK%2B/Inspector):

> GtkInspector is the built-in interactive debugging support in GTK+. It
>   was added in GTK+ 3.14, based on a copy of the well-estabished
>   *gtkparasite*. To enable the debugger, either start your app with
>   `GTK_DEBUG=interactive` in your environment, or run
>   `gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.Debug enable-inspector-keybinding true` and launch the
>   debugger with the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> keyboard
>   shortcuts.

[image]

Comment: I'm getting: `No such schema 'org.gtk.Settings.Debug'`

Comment: @jhasse -what's your gtk version ?

Comment: 3.16 on Ubuntu GNOME 15.10

Comment: For Ubuntu, see http://askubuntu.com/a/748152/248158